# Understanding Promises: Need to combine multiple results

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

How do I process the results of more than one Promise?
Say the results a of DoA and b of DoB in DoNext

I read https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises
It introduces the "then"-Syntax which is supposed to replace the "callback pyramid of doom" however I don't understand the following:

```
DoA.then(function(a){
    return DoB(a)
})
.then(function(b){
    DoNext(a,b);
})
```

In the call of DoNext, a is unknown. I understand that this is because a is only defined in the anonymous function in line 2. However in the "callback pyramid of doom" I can access a, because in that pattern DoNext is within the anonymous function that is the success callback of DoA.
How do I handle this in then-Syntax?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of handling multiple Promise situation.

1- Chain Promise (ugly though)

```
DoA.then(a => {
    DoB(a).then(.....)

})
.catch(error => console.log(error));
```

2- [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
var promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
var promise2 = 42;
var promise3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(function(values) {
  console.log(values);
});
// expected output: Array [3, 42, "foo"]
```

3- [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) (but read the details)

```
(async () => {

  const a = await DoA(); // DoA must be a Promise
  const b = await DoB(a); // DoB must be a Promise
  // rest of the code

})();
```