# How to store data that persists after close using an extension in Firefox

Tags: javascript, local-storage, es6-promise, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am writing a Firefox extension using WebExtension which stores data of the tabs open in a window and saves it for later use. It is similar to a feature in MS Edge. 
To store persisting data I am using storage.local API
However as I am testing whether the storage and retrieval of data is working, I am having trouble retrieving the data. I should also probably mention that I am new to Promises.

I have an object dataToStore{id,tabs[],numOfTabs,tags} which I send to be stored using `browser.storage.local.set(dataToStore);`

Then I have an object dataRetrieved{} which is used to store the return of `browser.storage.local.get(null)` which returns a Promise

Here is the code:

```
//At this state dataToStore has the necessary data inserted in it
console.log(dataToStore);
browser.storage.local.set(dataToStore);
let dataRetrieved={};
dataRetrieved = browser.storage.local.get(null).then(() => {
   console.log(dataRetrieved);
});
```

The output of `console.log(dataToStore);` is:

```
Object { id: 1563507620695, tabs: (3) […], numOfTabs: 3, tags: null }
```

which is as expected.
However the output of `console.log(dataRetrieved);` is:

```
Promise { <state>: "pending" }
```

I was expecting both the outputs to be same. As far as I know, the lines within .then is supposed to run only after the promise has returned value. However this does not seem to be the case here.
How do I access the stored value?

Reference:
[MDN for storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/StorageArea)

[Example of it from MDN Github](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/blob/master/annotate-page/sidebar/panel.js) lines 19,33

[MDN for StorageArea.get()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/StorageArea/get)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Promise` is an `async` function which means it will be placed in a queue and done in order.

Once it starts, if you need a result from the `Promise` you have to wait for it to finish the job.

Please also read my answer to: [Understanding Promises: Need to combine multiple results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53922275/understanding-promises-need-to-combine-multiple-results)

For example, in your code

```
(async () => {

  console.log(dataToStore);
  await browser.storage.local.set(dataToStore); // wait for it to be done before going to the next line
  const dataRetrieved = await browser.storage.local.get(); // wait for it
  console.log(dataRetrieved);
})();
```

You can also change them

```
console.log(dataToStore);
browser.storage.local.set(dataToStore).then(() => {
  // after it is done
  browser.storage.local.get().then((dataRetrieved) => {
    // after it is done
    console.log(dataRetrieved);

  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I was able to get it working using the second code block.